# Find the minimum of one number

Tags: statistics

> We are given some observations of the Random Variable $X$: 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5.
>   Find $\min \sum_{i=1}^{7} (x(i)-c)^{2}$.

I think that $c$ is the average of the given numbers but what do I do after I find the sum?

How do I find the minimum of only number?

Comment: What is your question? You are correct that the minimizing value of $c$ is the mean $\frac{1}{7} \sum_{i=1}^7 x(i)$.

Comment: Well if we find c then we can calculate the sum of (x(i)-c)^{2} to be some number. So how do we find a minimum of one number?

Comment: Consider the function $f(x) = x^2$. If you know $x$ then you can calculate $f(x)$, which is then a single number. Does that mean that you can't find the minimum value of $f$?

Comment: I think that the minimization is over $c$. You take the derivative with respect to c and equate it to 0 to get the extrema (in this case minimum). The minimizer $c^*$ turns out to be exactly the average, then to compute the minimum just plug in $c^*$ and evaluate the sum.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the point is to prove it formally? Consider minimizing
$$
f(c) = \sum_{i=1}^n (x_k-c)^2
$$
and note that $f$ is a polynomial in $c$ and hence is differentiable. You have
$$
f'(c) = 2 \sum_{i=1}^n (x_k-c) = 2 \sum_{i=1}^n x_k - 2cn,
$$
therefore
$$
f'(c) = 0 \iff 2cn = 2\sum_{k=1}^n x_k \iff c = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k.
$$

---

In the final analysis, if the average of the input is denoted $a$, the minimum is given by
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n (x_k-a)^2,
$$
which is a scale of the variance of the input.